# Movimentação de forms c#

Tags: c#

Tenho um menu e alguns forms filhos...e quero que não consigam clicar no form e arrastar, como eu faço ? Quero que ele fique parado na posição e tamanho que eu coloquei.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Tens algum exemplo do código que já tentaste fazer? Poderias postá-lo juntamente com a tua pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Bom não entendi muito mas pelo que eu entendi vc não quer que o usuário consiga redimensionar o form marque essa opção nas propriedades

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Isso trava o form e não permite redimensionar , fora isso desabilite a propriedade MaximizeBox, coloque-a em false para travar o botão de maximizar do form

o então para bloquear o movimento
pega esse código e cola la no código do form

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
            const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

            switch (message.Msg)
            {
                case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                    int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                    if (command == SC_MOVE)
                        return;
                    break;
            }

            base.WndProc(ref message);
        }
```

Comment: se eu clico no form seguro o botão esquerdo do mouse e arrasto ele mexe, entendeu ? eu não quero que ele mexxa

Comment: a entendi vc não quer alem disso que o usuario não mova o form pela tela

Comment: simmmm Filipe. Pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Tai na resposta editei ela ve o código que eu coloquei nela  pega ele cola la na class do form

Comment: então em cada form que eu quiser que fique imóvel devo digitar todo esse código ?!

Comment: Sim vc coloca esse código na class do form que vc quer que fique imovel da um ctrl+c nele ai e vai dando ctrl+v nos forms que vc não quer que se mova

Comment: ta legal , vou tentar

Comment: valeu meu querido , deu certo ! muito obrigado !!!

Comment: Opa por nada !!